# Redirect after login in Server-side Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

After I login to a Blazor server-side application, how do I redirect the user back to the page they were on before they clicked the Login button?

Comment: What authentication method are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is ASP.NET Identity.